# Autopopulate data based on a reference cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, auto-populate

I need excel to auto-populate data from A1:C20 to F4:H7 based on the employee ID (F2) that I input. I have no idea what function to use. I have attached a photo so you can see. Please and thank you!

I have used VLookup, but because the data is formatted in such a way I can't use that formula.

[Employee Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9gTs.png)

Comment: Auto-populate from where?  I'ts difficult to tell what you're really asking, but have you tried VLOOKUP() ?

Comment: Also you didn't actually attach a photo.

Comment: Sorry, new to the website, I've updated the question with the photo.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the below formula in cell `G4` and drag it down and then right to the next column,

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH($F$2,$B:$B,0)+ROW(2:2),0)
```

[image]

Whenever you change the ID, the values will be automatically populated. You need to handle the errors using `IFERROR` in case if you enter empty value in the cell `F2`.